# Ansible in-memory inventory from openstack.cloud.server_info

Tags: ansible, openstack

I need to create a in-memory inventory to run playbook over overcloud instance, all instance are not directly exposed, only one server is exposed and can be used as "gateway" aka "JumpHost" aka "ProxyHost".

I have been accomplish this task whit the following tasks:

Get infos on the server I'm interested

```
...
  - name: detect gateway for the {{ project }} tenant
    openstack.cloud.server_info:
      cloud: "{{ project }}"
      server: "*gw*"
    register: gw_info
...
```

Then I extract the information of the FloatingIP associated to this instance:

```
...
- name: Register info of gateway for {{ project }} tenant
  set_fact:
    gw_ip: "{{ item.interface_ip }}"
  loop: "{{ gw_info.openstack_servers }}"
...
```

Once I get the infos  I need I collect infos to all instances in the tenant

```
...
- name: fetch instances on {{ project }} tenant
  openstack.cloud.server_info:
    cloud: "{{ project }}"
  register: servers_info
...
```

And finally create the in memory inventory with the necessary group from the instances metadata to run others play

```
...
- name: create in memory inventory
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ item.name }}"
    ansible_ssh_host: "{{ item.private_v4 }}"
    ansible_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -i {{ ssh_priv_ key }} -W %h:%p -q ansible@{{ gw_ip }}"'
    group:
      - "{{ item.metadata.tool }}"
      - "{{ item.metadata.environment }}"
  loop: "{{ servers_info.openstack_servers }}"
...
```

It's working play but are there a way to do this in a better way, maybe more "elegant"?

I have also a doubt on ansible module openstack.cloud.server_info, in the documentation have the parameter [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openstack/cloud/server_info_module.html#parameter-filters), I try to filter on metadata of the instance but it does not work.

I would prefer to use metadata instead server name for filter my gateway because like this if another instance get a name with the "gw" letter will be selected and my playbook may fails because the gw_ip facts may contain the wrong information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider reducing the number of tasks needed to run to generate this host list, with inventory plugins and DNS. Also makes standard inventory features possible, like caching for improved performance.

Create and use an  [`openstack.cloud.openstack`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openstack/cloud/openstack_inventory.html) inventory config and let it enumerate the hosts.  Probably want to set  `private: yes`.  Use `keyed_groups` to add groups named after the values of metadata, as this inventory implements [`Constructable`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html)

Define in vars what the jump host's name is. Possibly in `group_vars` so they only apply to this tenant/project/whatever.

```
# DNS FQDN of jump host
jumphost: jumphost.{{ project }}.example.net
# ProxyCommand or ProxyJump can be defined as ansible vars
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -i {{ ssh_priv_key }} -W %h:%p -q ansible@{{ jumphost }}"'
```

Run a play on `localhost` to fill in what the jump host is. Use `openstack.cloud.server_info` if that makes sense. Update AAAA and A DNS records of `{{ jumphost }}` with a task.  As long as this IP doesn't change, no tasks need to run to find it again.

Comment: Unfortunately designate module are not supported by our supplier :( this cause us many trouble (is a on-premise cloud installation). I was thinking to set some hook in dhcpclient to register name on bind9. But I did not find time yet to test it out. I proceed at this way because the project was just deployed by heat in a previous play. Anyway, thanks for your answer, I think I have to work on automatic DNS registration of instances.

Comment: Who has what problem with which part?  I mention DNS in a playbook only because you were getting the IP with Ansible as if you did not have a name service.  If the jump host should get a A record some other way, do that.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
  - name: detect gateway for the {{ project }} tenant
    openstack.cloud.server_info:
      cloud: "{{ project }}"
      server: "*gw*"
      filters:
        vm_state: active
        metadata: 
          bootstrap: "true"
    register: gw_info
```